# 'IParcelable[]' does not contain a definition for 'JavaCast'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to access JavaCast function while using the GetParcelableArrayExtra but cannot access it.
I am getting the error **'IParcelable[]' does not contain a definition for 'JavaCast' and the best extension method overload 'Extensions.JavaCast(IJavaObject)' requires a receiver of type 'IJavaObject'**

**MainActivity.cs**

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        
        if (data != null)
        {

            var myData =
                data.GetParcelableArrayExtra(CardIOActivity.ExtraScanResult).JavaCast<CreditCard>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
  var myData =
              data.GetParcelableArrayExtra(CardIOActivity.ExtraScanResult).JavaCast<CreditCard>();
```

USE

```
Bundle bundle = data.Extras;
                Dictionary<string, object> dict = bundle.KeySet()
                    .ToDictionary<string, string, object>(key => key, key => bundle.Get(key));
```